# Create React app stuck on npm audit and npm funds

Tags: reactjs

Create React app command stuck on `npm audit` and `npm funds`.

Screenshot of Problem: https://prnt.sc/t373lc

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation guide on https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

Try above and check if it solves the issues else try running `npm cache clean --force` before running create-react-app.

You can also turn off `npm audit`

```sh
npm set audit false
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows using NodeJS 64Bit.

After searching the internet, I have done what said in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62484536/6045800) to uninstall create-react-app globally and uninstalling the whole NodeJS from my computer and install the Nodejs 32Bit and it should work.

The reference where the issue was solved: [Reference](https://dev.to/gouthamigou/comment/mpkf)

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and run command resmon. This would open the resource monitor.
Look for cmd.exe process. Right click, and resume the process if suspended. Helped me.